# Compilar modulo de kernel linux

Tags: c, linux

Olá estou estudando sobre sistemas operacionais, através do livro: fundamentos de sistemas operacionais.
La no cap. 2 fala sobre os modulo de kernel e mostra um exemplo:
simples.c

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int simples_init(void) {
   printk(KERN_INFO,"Mod. Init");
   return 0;
}

void simples_exit(void) {
   printk(KERN_INFO,"Mod. Exit");
}

module_init(simples_init);
module_exit(simples_exit);
```

Esse é o codigo então como faço para compila-lo?

Comment: Sua dúvida é, "Como compilar um código simples escrito em C". O comando vai depender do compilador que estiver usando, no Linux tem o `gcc`. Acredito que o livro deva pressupor um conhecimento básico em C para acompanhar os códigos apresentados, se não pressupõe deveria.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar criar um Makefile no diretorio onde fica o `simples.c`. Assim voce pode chamar `make` para compilar e `make clean` para limpar a build. O resultado do seu build vai ser um objeto do kernel `simples.ko`. Para carregar o modulo `insmod simples.ko` ou `modprobe simples.ko`, vc pode ver seu modulo carregado rodando `lsmod`, para descarregar o modulo `rmmod simples.ko` ou `modprobe -r simples.ko`. Para ver a `string` que seu modulo imprimiu, `dmesg`

> obj-m += simples.o
>
> all:  make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
>
> clean:    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean